# Youtube Iframe Api not working within function

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

for some reason the youtube iframe api doesnt seem to work when i put it in a function like this

```
$.getVideo = (elem, id) => {
    $.getScript("https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api")

    var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player(elem, {
            videoId: id,
            playerVars: {
                autoplay: 1,
                autohide: 1,
                modestbranding: 0,
                rel: 0,
                showinfo: 0,
                controls: 0,
                disablekb: 1,
                enablejsapi: 1,
                iv_load_policy: 3
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            }
        })
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.mute()
    }
}
$.getVideo('player', 'CmRih_VtVAs')
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbBRpV

but it seems to work fine when ran outside a function?
what am i doing wrong?

i really need the function to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` must be available in the global scope.

Modify your functions in a way that the above function is being called, then load the library, and update player variable to the new instance.

```js
 var player; // global scope
 $.getVideo = (elem, id) => {

    var cb = () => {
        player = new YT.Player(elem, {
            videoId: id,
            playerVars: {
                autoplay: 1,
                autohide: 1,
                modestbranding: 0,
                rel: 0,
                showinfo: 0,
                controls: 0,
                disablekb: 1,
                enablejsapi: 1,
                iv_load_policy: 3
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            }
        })
    }
    
    window.onPlayerReady = function(event) {
        event.target.mute();
    }

    // Load YouTube SDK if not loaded
    if (!window.YT) {
        $.getScript("https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api");
        // update the global function to call cb
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = cb;
    // call cb()
    } else {
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => { }; // set it to dummy function
        cb();
    }

}
 
$.getVideo('player', 'CmRih_VtVAs')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
```

```
 var player; // global scope
 $.getVideo = (elem, id) => {

    var cb = () => {
        player = new YT.Player(elem, {
            videoId: id,
            playerVars: {
                autoplay: 1,
                autohide: 1,
                modestbranding: 0,
                rel: 0,
                showinfo: 0,
                controls: 0,
                disablekb: 1,
                enablejsapi: 1,
                iv_load_policy: 3
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            }
        })
    }

    // make this global
    window.onPlayerReady = function(event) {
        event.target.mute();
    }

    // Load YouTube SDK if not loaded
    if (!window.YT) {
        $.getScript("https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api");
        // update the global function to call cb
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = cb;
    // call cb()
    } else {
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => { }; // set it to dummy function
        cb();
    }

}
```